# How to mock NATS microservices?

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, nats.io

I want to test microservices. Microservices communicate via NATS. I see several test levels for it:
Unit testing - one container format;
Integration testing - several container formats;
e2e via GUI.

I can't find a solution for the first test level. How can I isolate  a container format that communicates with others via NATS protocol? I tried doing it based on [mountebank](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mountebank) via TCP, but that doesn't seem to be right.

How do you test your microservices in NATS? Does it make any sense to do it via TCP?